# how can I set the vehicle to drive at a constant speed in sumo file?

Tags: sumo

How can I set the vehicle to drive at a constant speed? I find the speed of vehicle increases firstly and then drive at speed between 14.5 and 14.7 m/s in sumo. But I want the car drive at a constant speed in sumo. What shuould I do?

**helloWorld.net.xml**

```
<net version="1.3" junctionCornerDetail="5" limitTurnSpeed="5.50" >
    <location netOffset="0.00,0.00" convBoundary="-300.00,0.00,300.00,0.00" origBoundary="10000000000.00,10000000000.00,-10000000000.00,-10000000000.00" projParameter="!"/>
    <edge id=":1_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1_0_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="0.10" shape="0.00,-1.60 0.00,-1.60"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="gneE0" from="0" to="1" priority="-1">
        <lane id="gneE0_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="300.00" shape="-300.00,-1.60 0.00,-1.60"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="gneE1" from="1" to="3" priority="-1">
        <lane id="gneE1_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="300.00" shape="0.00,-1.60 300.00,-1.60"/>
    </edge>
    <junction id="0" type="dead_end" x="-300.00" y="0.00" incLanes="" intLanes="" shape="-300.00,0.00 -300.00,-3.20"/>
    <junction id="1" type="priority" x="0.00" y="0.00" incLanes="gneE0_0" intLanes=":1_0_0" shape="0.00,0.00 0.00,-3.20 0.00,0.00">
        <request index="0" response="0" foes="0" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="3" type="dead_end" x="300.00" y="0.00" incLanes="gneE1_0" intLanes="" shape="300.00,-3.20 300.00,0.00"/>
    <connection from="gneE0" to="gneE1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":1_0_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1_0" to="gneE1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
</net>
```

**hello.rou.xml**

```
<routes >
    <route edges="gneE0 gneE1" color="yellow" id="route_0"/>
    <vehicle id="vehicle_0" depart="0.00" color="red" route="route_0"/>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable random dawdling by setting sigma to 0 and start with the maximum speed. To do so you need to define a vehicle type:

```
<routes>
    <vType sigma="0" id="t1"/>
    <route edges="gneE0 gneE1" color="yellow" id="route_0"/>
    <vehicle id="vehicle_0" depart="0.00" color="red" route="route_0" departSpeed="max" type="t1"/>
</routes>
```

Comment: And if I want the vehicle to decelerate at a certain deceleration, what should I do?

Comment: For online vehicle behavior changes have a look at traci: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI.html